# Mapster Not Mapping Nested Collections Correctly in .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net-core, mapping, mapster

I am having an issue with mapping nested collections using Mapster in .NET 7. The mapping seems to fail for the second-level collection (Bs inside A). This is surprising because, during debugging, I can see that A does have Bs with Cs.

Here are my domain classes:

```cs
public class TestA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TestB> TestBs { get; set; } = new List<TestB>();
}

public class TestB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TestA? TestA { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TestC> TestCs { get; set; } = new List<TestC>();
}

public class TestC
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And here are my DTOs:

```cs
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; } = new List<B>();
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public A? A { get; set; }
    public ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; } = new List<C>();
}

public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Mapster configuration:

```cs
public class TestMapping : IRegister
{
    public void Register(TypeAdapterConfig config)
    {
        config
            .NewConfig<TestA, A>()
            .Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id)
            .Map(dest => dest.Bs, src => src.TestBs.Adapt<List<B>>());

        config
            .NewConfig<TestB, B>()
            .Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id)
            .Map(dest => dest.A, src => src.TestA == null ? null : src.TestA.Adapt<A>())
            .Map(dest => dest.Cs, src => src.TestCs.Adapt<List<C>>());

        config
            .NewConfig<TestC, C>()
            .Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
    }
}
```

And here is how I am testing it:

```cs
public async Task<dynamic> Test()
{
    TestA a1 = new TestA { Id = 1 };

    TestB b1 = new TestB { Id = 1, TestA = a1 };
    TestB b2 = new TestB { Id = 2, TestA = a1 };

    TestC c1 = new TestC { Id = 1, };
    TestC c2 = new TestC { Id = 2, };

    b1.TestCs = new List<TestC> { c1 };
    b2.TestCs = new List<TestC> { c2 };

    a1.TestBs = new List<TestB> { b1, b2 };

    var mappedA = _mapper.Map<A>(a1);

    return mappedA;
}
```

Output:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "bs": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "a": null,
            "cs": [] // should contain list of C
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "a": null,
            "cs": [] // should contain list of C
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run this test, mappedA contains Bs, but Bs do not contain Cs. Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Nested collection C is not being mapped.

Comment: Have the same problem. Gave up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a circular reference.

`TestA` have a `List<TestB>` and `TestB` also have a reference to `TestA`, therefore Mapster will start to map `TestA => A` and then map `TestB => B` now because `TestB` reference `TestA` Mapster will then go back to mapping `TestA => B` resulting in an infinite loop.

You have two options.

**Option 1:**
Remove the reference to `TestA` in `TestB`

**Option 2:**
Update your MapsterConfig to include the `PreserveReference(true)`

```
config.NewConfig<TestA, A>()
                .Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id)
                .Map(dest => dest.Bs, src => src.TestBs.Adapt<List<B>>());

config.NewConfig<TestB, B>()
                .Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id)
                .Map(dest => dest.A, src => src.TestA == null ? null : src.TestA.Adapt<A>())
                .Map(dest => dest.Cs, src => src.TestCs.Adapt<List<C>>())
                .PreserveReference(true);

config.NewConfig<TestC, C>()
                .Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
```

Comment: 1. One is not optimal for my use case. Almost all the models have circular references and creating new domain models just to satisfy this criteria seems overkill to me.

2. I have set PreserveReference(true) on each config and globally as well. This produces the same result.

I have used the exact same models with AutoMapper and it is correctly handling the circular reference.